# Limit decimal numbers in html and where to put the script

Tags: html, scripting, numbers, output, decimal

So I’ve got a program that prints a html report with some numbers from within the program.
The output number includes 6 decimals, but I want to limit it to 2 decimals..
I’ve read a bunch of articles about coding it, but lacking basic understanding of this type of coding, I need help to write the code.

The code looks like this within the program:

```
<HTML>

<P align="center">
<img src="image.png">
</P>

<FONT face="Tahoma" size=4 color="Blue">
<P align="center">Rapport</P>
</FONT>

<FONT face="Arial" size=2 color="Black">
<P align="center"><strong>{Date} {Time}</strong></P>

<TABLE border="1" align="center">
<TR>
<TH bgcolor="lightYellow">Vatn 1</TH>
<TH bgcolor="lightYellow">Vatn 2</TH>
<TH bgcolor="lightYellow">Salt</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD bgcolor="#C6DEFF">{vatn1}</TH>
<TD bgcolor="#C6DEFF">{vatn2}</TH>
<TD bgcolor="#C6DEFF">{salt}</TH>
</TR>

</TABLE>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Prenta síðuna</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.print();
}
</script>
<input type="button" align="center" value="Lukka síðu" onclick="self.close()">

</FONT>

</HTML>
```

And after printed, ready to open in the browser:

```
<HTML>

<P align="center">
<img src="image.png">
</P>

<FONT face="Tahoma" size=4 color="Blue">
<P align="center">Rapport</P>
</FONT>

<FONT face="Arial" size=2 color="Black">
<P align="center"><strong>{Date} {Time}</strong></P>

<TABLE border="1" align="center">
<TR>
<TH bgcolor="lightYellow">Vatn 1</TH>
<TH bgcolor="lightYellow">Vatn 2</TH>
<TH bgcolor="lightYellow">Salt</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD bgcolor="#C6DEFF">{1.000000}</TH>
<TD bgcolor="#C6DEFF">{2.000000}</TH>
<TD bgcolor="#C6DEFF">{3.000000}</TH>
</TR>

</TABLE>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Prenta síðuna</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.print();
}
</script>
<input type="button" align="center" value="Lukka síðu" onclick="self.close()">

</FONT>

</HTML>
```

So as far as I know I need a script to process the number, what should it look like and where in my file do I place it? Also whatever tag the edited number ends up in, how do I insert it in the table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Elrike. I'm not sure if I understood what you meant. but i think you want to see 1.11 as a result. my answer is not complete but there is a simple function in javascript to do that ".toFixed(2)"

Comment: If you are dealing with financial data, you should be aware that this function may round numbers

Comment: That is correct. I want to see 1.11

Comment: The data is weight, and the user wants less decimals because the data isn’t that accurate, so 6 decimal places could make it look like it’s super accurate

Comment: In that case I think you can use "toFixed" function :)

Comment: I suggest you create a new HTML file before trying to change the original project and try this function separately there :)

Comment: <html>
    <script>
        let number=1.1103;
        number=number.toFixed(2);
        alert(number);
    </script>
</html>

Comment: Thanks. So I can’t put that piece of code directly in my table, correct? So I have to put it separately somewhere in the file, and then I’ll just leave {number} in the table?

Comment: actually you can use a trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to give any more info on the program you are using to do this, please?

At a basic level, (depending on your program) scripts can be put on a webpage in-between `<script></script>` tags.

Now, by looking at the `<td>{number}</td>` I would assume it is a [template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor) of some kind.

If it can do it, try `<td>{nuumber.toFixed(2)}</td>`

As it's been mentioned, using `toFixed(2)` on financial data can round numbers incorrectly.

Out of the scope of these question but [this article explains why.](https://frontstuff.io/how-to-handle-monetary-values-in-javascript) (Slightly advance but linked for anyone else wondering why!)

I would suggest a better way but without knowing what you're using and the environment that would be too much assumption.

Comment: The program is simply producing a txt file, inserting the numbers in a report. 
The script tags you mentioned are used at the end of the file, but I read somewhere that I might need to put the script earlier on in the code.
I’ve tried messing around with the toFixed function, but couldn’t make it work, I’ll try your suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: Are you able to share the full/relevant code and update your questions with it? We might be able to help you out faster then.

Comment: I've edited my question, to contain the entire code, the one used by the program to insert the values in the report. And what it looks like after the program has produced the report, when opened in notes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the information is bound in HTML, so you can change it after the data is loaded.

---

you can change this block:

```
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            window.print();
        }
    </script>
```

to this one; This is not a good method but it works as a trick:

```
    /*Important to know (1)*/
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            window.print();
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
            $("td").each((i, e) => {
                e = $(e);
                let data = e.html().replace("}", "").replace("{", "");
                e.html(parseFloat(data).toFixed(2));
            });
        }, 1000);

    </script>
```

(1) Download JQuery and link the HTML to it.

[image]

---

Also if you do not want to use JQuery you can use pure javascript like this:

```
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            window.print();
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
            let tags = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                let html = tags[i].innerHTML;
                html = html.split("{").join("").split("}").join("")
                tags[i].innerHTML = parseFloat(html).toFixed(2);
            }
        }, 1000);
    </script>
```

Comment: Will both of these also work if, say, the decimals weren’t all zeros?